# Hide specific date, only show weekday

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm having a problem, trying to adjust the agendaWeek and agendaDay view: I am using FullCalendar to display information which is not based on a specific date (e.g. Tuesday 19th of August 2014) but only on weekday basis (e.g. Tuesday).

To better handle this information it is stored as dates in the first full week of January 2014. That works like a charm however, if the information is displayed in FullCalendar it always displays "Mo, 6th", "Tue 7th" etc.

Is it possible to adjust the FullCalendar settings so the table header just shows "Mo", "Tue" etc.?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks drmarvelous! I don't know why I did not consider that but there is an easy setting for that in the default config:

```
columnFormat: {
    week: 'ddd',
},
```